# Why can't I extend an Express Request Type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
interface IUserRequest extends Request {
  user: User;
}


  async use(req: IUserRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const apiKey: string = String(req.headers['x-api-key']).trim();
```

But TypeScript 3.7.4, complains: `Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'IUserRequest'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow - that was silly. Turns out my `express` was in `devDependencies`. Once I installed those, it worked flawlessly.